# Pick up the longest peptide using perl

Tags: perl

I want to find out the longest possible protein sequence translated from cds in 6 forward and reverse frame.

This is the example input format:

```
>111
KKKKKKKMGFSOXLKPXLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX
>222
WWWMPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPMPPPPPXKKKKKK
```

I would like to find out all the strings which start from "M" and stop at "X", count the each length of the strings and select the longest.

For example, in the case above:

the script will find,

```
>111 has two matches:
MGFSOX
MJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX
>222 has one match:
MPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPMPPPPPX
```

Then count each match's length, and print the string and number of longest matches which is the result I want:

```
>111
MJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX    32
>222
MPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPMPPPPPX    38
```

But it prints out no answer. Does anyone know how to fix it? Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my @pep=();
my $i=();
my @Xnum=();
my $n=();
my %hash=();
my @k=();
my $seq=();
$n=0;
open(IN, "<$ARGV[0]");
while(<IN>){
        chomp;
        if($_=~/^[^\>]/){
                @pep=split(//, $_);
                if($_ =~ /(X)/){
                        push(@Xnum, $1);
                        if($n >= 0 && $n <= $#Xnum){
                                if(@pep eq "M"){
                                        for($i=1; $i<=$#pep; $i++){
                                                $seq=join("",@pep);
                                                $hash{$i}=$seq;
                                                push(@k, $i);
                                        }
                                }
                                elsif(@pep eq "X"){
                                        $n=$n+1;
                                        }
                                foreach (sort {$a cmp $b} @k){
                                        print "$hash{$k[0]}\t$k[0]";
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        elsif($_=~/^\>/){
                print "$_\n";
        }

}
close IN;
```

Comment: Ah, I'd love to help, but you'd have to explain this in general term; not everyone is up-to-date on their bio. Please define a clear problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I have revised my question.

Comment: Do you mind posting some example input?

Comment: yep, please check the first box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this Perl one-liner

```
$ cat iris.txt
>111
KKKKKKKMGFSOXLKPXLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX
>222
WWWMPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPMPPPPPXKKKKKK

$ perl -ne ' if(!/^>/) { print "$p"; while(/(M[^M]+?X)/g ) { if(length($1)>length($x)) {$x=$1 }  } print "$x ". length($x)."\n";$x="" } else { $p=$_ }  ' iris.txt
>111
MJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX 32
>222
MPPPPPX 7

$
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it!

Try this too:

```
print and next if /^>/;
chomp and my @z = $_ =~ /(M[^X]*X)/g;

my $m = "";
for my $s (@z) {
    $m = $s if length $s > length $m
}
say "$m\t" . length $m
```

Output:

```
>111
MJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX    32
>222
MPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPMPPPPPX  38
```

*uses >=5.14 and make sure to run script with `perl -n`*

---

As a one-liner:

```
perl -E 'print and next if /^>/; chomp and my @z = $_ =~ /(M[^X]*X)/g; my $m = ""; for my $s (@z) { $m = $s if length $s > length $m } say "$m\t" . length $m' -n data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using `reduce` from `List::Util`.

Edit: mistakenly used `maxstr` which gave results but is not what was needed. Have reedited this post to use `reduce` (correctly) instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/reduce/;

open my $fh, '<', \<<EOF;
>111
KKKKKKKMGFSOXLKPXLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJX
>222
WWWMPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPMPPPPPXKKKKKK
EOF

my $id;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>/) {
        $id = $_;   
    }
    else {
        my $data = reduce {length($a) > length($b) ? $a : $b} /M[^X]*X/g;
        print "$id\n$data\t" . length($data) . "\n" if $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.

I like fasta files tucked into a hash, with the fasta name as the key. This way you can just add descriptions to it, e.g. base composition etc...

```
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.20/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my %prot;

open (my $fh, '<', '/Users/me/Desktop/fun_prot.fa') or die $!;
my $string = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;
chomp $string;
my @fasta = grep {/./} split (">", $string);
for my $aa (@fasta){
    my ($key, $value) = split ("\n", $aa);
    $value =~ s/[A-Z]*(M.*M)[A-Z]/$1/;
    $prot{$key}->{'len'} = length($value);
    $prot{$key}->{'prot'} = $value;
    }
for my $sequence (sort { $prot{$b}->{'len'} <=> $prot{$a}->{'len'} } keys %prot){
    print ">" . $sequence, "\n", $prot{$sequence}->{'prot'}, "\t", $prot{$sequence}->{'len'}, "\n";
    last;
}     
__DATA__
>1232
ASDFASMJJJJJMFASDFSDAFSDDFSA
>2343
AASFDFASMJJJJJJJJJJJJJJMRGQEGDAGDA
```

**Output**

```
>2343
MJJJJJJJJJJJJJJM  16
```

Comment: Thanks for the concept!! Sorry for my late reply.
Actually, my main purpose is to find out the longest isoform to do domain identify from RNA-seq data. But it seems that length() may solve it here.

Comment: Modified accordingly.